# How to change google custom search result on mywebsite?

Tags: google-custom-search

I fetch google custom search result in a iframe and displayed the result on my website.

```
<iframe 
      id='result'
      src='" . $strURL . "'
      width='102%' height='1420px'
      style='border:none' border='0'>
</iframe>
```

Now, I want to change the css of google result, like margin between results, take pagination to top instead bottom, change pagination css style.

Here is my site link: http://technovinity.com/demo/gse/

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly common to add CSS styles to match the google custom tags.

For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
.gs-title { background:red; }
</style>
```